# Extracting data form Facebook comments

Tags: facebook, web-scraping

I need to extract comments from a certain Facebook post into excell. For example from this post https://web.facebook.com/fortebet.ug/photos/a.1452160851664455/2193264900887376/?type=3  to extract all comments, but to have columns for the usernames, their Facebook ID, the comment itself, and time of the comment.

Also I am facing a problem that specificaly for this post  Facebook is showing there should be 800+ comments, but I am able to display only around 500 even manually.

I am really new to this, so I would appreciate any help, thank you.

B.

EDIT:

Have tried Graph APE Explorer - https://developers.facebook.com/tools but from that I was able to get only those information:
      "created_time": "2018-08-24T08:50:26+0000",
      "message": "Manchester united 1:1 spurs rashford to score.",
      "id": "2193265097554023_2193330367547496"
and need to get the username of the users who commented and most preferably also their FB ID.

Also as mentioned had a problem that on this post Facebook is displaying there are over 800comments, but able to retrieve only around 500, not more.

Comment: please add what you have tried so far (api call, code, debug info, ...), and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Have tried graph explorer and than open refine to get the export. But I could get only the comments and the time of the comment without the username who commented. Also was not able to get all comments of that post..

Comment: do you own the page? and again, i have to ask you to add what you have tried so far. in the question, NOT in comments. "tried graph explorer" is no useful information at all.

Comment: Yes I am one of the owner of the page. Sorry for not putting the correct information, I am really new to this. Have edited the initial post with hopefully enough..

Comment: and how about the api call for the api explorer? that would be the most important thing. are you using a page token of that page? are you using the fields parameter?

Comment: I used "get user access token"

Comment: this is what I have used to get the info:

GET https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/2193264900887376/comments?limit=500000

Comment: About field paramaters I guess not, have not put anything there..

Answer (score 0):

You have missed 2 important things:

- You must use a Page Token of the Page in question to get user details
- You have to use the fields parameter to get more than just some basic response fields

Check out the basic Graph API docs first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at it!

Comment: I went trought it, thank you for that. But still didn´t find the answer. I have the tokens - I have used user token, and page token, but still the field I need "from" say "field is empty or disallowed by the access token". And I have really used everything..

Comment: you need to add the exact api call in your question

Comment: Well this is the call I am putting in: 2193264900887376?fields=comments.limit(50000).order(chronological){from,message,created_time}

but I am not getting nothing from the field "from" which I need

Comment: wow, 50000....that limit will definitely not work...and why the brackets for from, message and created_time?

Comment: yes the 50000 is too much I realize that, just was wondering how come when Facebook is showing it has 800+ comments I get only around 500.. About the brackets not sure why its there, what is the correct syntax? But still I am getting all information needed only the field "from" is not available and I have no idea why.. The only think it says when I move the mouse over it, it says "field is empty or disallowed by access token". Which I dont understand as it is not emply and have try everything with the access token..

Comment: there is usually an internal max limit for api calls. i guess it´s 500 for comments.

Comment: well actually what I found out is that it is not displaying deleted comments.. But I would need to see them too.. But still having the problem that I cant who has commented. Also no idea how to display that?

Comment: maybe facebook removed that possibility completely? i would not be surprised, to be honest.

Comment: That is also what I tought, but still if it is possible to get that data manually and moreover from a public page, why would they do that.. Anyway, thank you for your help. Appreciate it.